# Convert object to array and remove object instance

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this object-array, there could (!) be structure mistakes like shown below, which I need to get corrected. As you can see, `data` should be an array with objcts. Sometimes it is an object, which has an object. In this example the last element of `group` has the field `"1"`, which is wrong. This field name could have different names. I need to remove that.

```
{
    "group" : [
        {
            "title" : "title 1",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum",
                    "field 2" : "dolor"
                },
                {
                    "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum",
                    "field 2" : "dolor"
                },
                {
                    "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum",
                    "field 2" : "dolor"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "data" : {  // <-- should be array
                "1" : { // <-- wrong
                    "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum",
                    "field 2" : "dolor"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The result should be:

```
{
    "group" : [
        {
            "title" : "title 1",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum",
                    "field 2" : "dolor"
                },
                {
                    "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum",
                    "field 2" : "dolor"
                },
                {
                    "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum",
                    "field 2" : "dolor"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum",
                    "field 2" : "dolor"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates this object ?

Comment: It does not look like a hard problem. Why haven't you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = {
    "group" : [{
            "title" : "title 1",
            "data" : [
                { "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum" }
            ]
        }, {
            "data" : {
                "1" : { "field 1" : "Lorem ipsum" }
            }
        }
    ]
};

// check each group
data.group.forEach(function (g) {
    // is it an array (simple check for "length" property)
    if (typeof g.data.length === "undefined") {
        // if not, convert "data" to an array and replace it in-place
        g.data = Object.keys(g.data).map(function (d) {
                return g.data[d];
            })
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```